Trying to understand an algorithm for corner detection
There's a paper called "Corner detection based on tangent-to-point distance accumulation technique" that I'm trying to implement.
The basic premise of the paper is that you have a shape that is composed of points in 2d space. For each point you take a neighborhood of points around it, calculate some tangents and through that you get a discrete value for the curvature at that point.
I've implemented it but there is something wrong, or I am fundamentally misunderstanding something in the mathematics.
If this is not the right forum for this kind of question I would greatly appreciate if someone knows a better place to ask this question.
The paper can be found here "https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-019-07792-x#Sec7" for reference, but I'll include the relevant mathematics that matter for this post.
Please bear with me as I walk through it and explain my understanding. Hopefully, that will give enough context for the parts where I'm missing something.

In the following, we present a novel “discrete curvature” estimation technique based on the above described basic idea. Let m sequential digital points describe a contour $C, C = {pj = (x_j, y_j), j = 1, 2, ⋯, m}$, where $p_j + 1$ is adjacent to $p_j$. Denote $N_k(p_i)$ as a small boundary segment of $C$, which is defined by the RoS (region of support) between points $p_i − k$ and $p_i + k$ for some integer $k$, i.e. $N_k(p_i) = {p_j| j = i − k, ⋯, i + k}$. Our aim is to calculate the “discrete curvature” at the point $p_i$.

So far, so good. We have a contour with sequential digital points and we have a small boundary segment for each point.

To achieve this aim, we parameterize the 2k + 1 points and can get two parameterized point sets ${\left\{\left(j,\kern0.5em {x}_{i+j}\right)\right\}}_{j=-k}^{\kern0.75em k}$ and ${\left\{\left(j,\kern0.5em {y}_{i+j}\right)\right\}}_{j=-k}^{\kern0.75em k}$. According to the least squares criterion, we respectively fit the polynomial series: $\mathrm{x}\left(\mathrm{t}\right)={\sum}_{n=0}^2{\alpha}_n{t}^n$ and $\mathrm{y}\left(\mathrm{t}\right)={\sum}_{n=0}^2{\beta}_n{t}^n$  to the point sets ${(j,  x_i + j)}$ and ${(j,  y_i + j)}$, where $j =  − k, ⋯, − 1, 1, ⋯, k,$ $x(0) = x_i$ and $y(0) = y_i$. The coefficients $α = (α_0,  α_1,  α_2)$ and $β = (β_0,  β_1,  β_2)$ are estimated as follows:


$\underset{\boldsymbol{α}}{\boldsymbol{α} =\mathrm{argmin}}\sum \limits_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^{\kern0.50em \ k}{\left(\mathrm{x}(j)-{x}_{i+j}\right)}^2,\mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}\ \mathrm{x}(0)={x}_i$


$\underset{\boldsymbol{β}}{\boldsymbol{β} =\mathrm{argmin}}\sum \limits_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^{\kern0.50em \ k}{\left(\mathrm{y}(j)-{y}_{i+j}\right)}^2,s.t\ \mathrm{y}(0)={y}_i$

Ok. So parsing this out we're choosing two quadratic polynomials that are least-squared fitted to the parameterized points. The quadratic formulas will look like:
$α_0 t^0 + α _1 t^1 + α _2 t^2 = α_0 + α _1 t + α _2 t^2$
and
$ β_0 t^0 + β _1 t^1 + β_2 t^2 = β_0 + β _1 t + β _2 t^2$
such that the values $(α_0, α_1, a_2)$ and $(β_0, β_1, β_2)$ minimize the value of the least squares summation.
Now comes a leap:

By solving the above two optimization problems with constraints, we have


${α}_1=\frac{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{x}_{i+j}-{x}_ij}{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{j}^2}=\frac{3}{k\left(k+1\right)\left(2k+1\right)}\sum \limits_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{x}_{i+j}-{x}_ij$


${β}_1=\frac{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{y}_{i+j}-{y}_ij}{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{j}^2}=\frac{3}{k\left(k+1\right)\left(2k+1\right)}\sum \limits_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{y}_{i+j}-{y}_ij$

What in the heck just happened? And why is it only $α_1$ and $β_1$? (Apparently, I found out by reading on carefully, it's because we only care about the tangent line at the current point $p_i$ and the other two parameters, $α_0$ and $α_2$ don't matter)
Can someone help me figure out how we got to this derivation? It might help me figure out what's gone wrong. It feels odd that we're multiplying by $j$.

I just added "image-processing" tag.

Is there something common with Harris corner detector ?

@Yves Daoust Thanks.

@YvesDaoust I'm afraid the gap between my understanding and your hint is too great.

Turns out there's an error in the paper.
This:
${β}_1=\frac{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{y}_{i+j}-{y}_ij}{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{j}^2}=\frac{3}{k\left(k+1\right)\left(2k+1\right)}\sum \limits_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{y}_{i+j}-{y}_ij$
Should actually be:
${β}_1=\frac{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k({y}_{i+j}-{y}_i)j}{\sum_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k{j}^2}=\frac{3}{k\left(k+1\right)\left(2k+1\right)}\sum \limits_{j=-k,j\ne 0}^k({y}_{i+j}-{y}_i) j$
